# The 'error' in the Jenkinsfile, does not get executed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a jenkinsfile, which calls a shared library. For eg:
Jenkinsfile-

```
@Library('test-shared-library') _
testAndPack{
    //container = ''

    PIPELINE = [
                ["type": "python",
                "name": "Dummy",
                "stage": "Run python",
                "folder": "build",
                "script": "python3 HelloWorld.py",
                
                ],
                ["type": "Pack",
                "name": "DummyCombination",
                "stage":"Pack To Zip",
                "script": "echo packing to zip",
                "artefacts": "*.zip"
                ],
            ]
    triggerGenerateCodePipeline = true
}
```

The testAndPack.groovy looks like this:

```
def call(body) {
    // Confuration from the argument
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()
    try{
        for (val in config.PIPELINE){
                    
                   if (val.type == "python"){
                        run_python(val)
                    }else if (val.type == "Pack"){
                       perform_packing(val)
                    }
                }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
         BUILD_STATUS ="FAILURE"
    }
}

def run_python(val){
   stage(val.name) {
     node {
        checkout scm
      BUILD_STATUS = sh ( script: "ls && cd ${val.folder} && ${val.script}",
                          returnStatus: true
                        ) == 0
      echo "${BUILD_STATUS}"
  if (BUILD_STATUS) {
          echo "${val.name} was build correctly "
      } else {    
         error "#### build_step ${val.name} failed ####"//Even here it doesn't print when failure
      }
    }
   }
}

def perform_packing(val){
   stage(val.name) {
      node {
      def BUILD_STATUS = sh (returnStatus: true, script: "ls && zip -r build.zip build")==0
       echo "${BUILD_STATUS}"   
      if (BUILD_STATUS) {
          echo "${STAGE_NAME} was build correctly "
      } else {    
          echo "before error"
          error "There is a failure" //Does not print
          echo "after error"
          //throw new Exception("Something went wrong!")
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Currently, the zip tool isnot present in the node. So I expect an error to be thrown and build to fail. However, the response is the following [image: Jenkins Response].

Am I missing something here?
The error  construct seems to work on a simple pipeline though.(Just eliminating the scenario if its based on a plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I expect an error to be thrown and build to fail.

This is currently half true: an error is being thrown, but the build is not failing. The error is being explicitly caught by the invoking code higher on the stack:

```
try { ... }
catch(Exception e) {
  BUILD_STATUS = "FAILURE"
}
```

To additionally mark the build as a failure you would need to modify the `result` member of the `currentBuild` object to be assigned the string value of `FAILURE`:

```
if (BUILD_STATUS) {
  echo "${val.name} was build correctly "
} else {    
  error "#### build_step ${val.name} failed ####"//Even here it doesn't print when failure
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

alternatively to conform to your current style:

```
try { ... }
catch(Exception e) {
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

but this alternate implementation of course also prevents the error message from flushing to the `stderr` descriptor, and so you would need to explicitly log it beforehand if you want to view it in the Jenkins Pipeline logs.